# how should pass a parameter from form to a search action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search form in my application layout like below :

```
 %li 
            %form{:method => 'get' , :action => :search }
              %input{:type=>'text',:length => "10"}
              %input{:type=>'submit' , :value => 'search'}
```

and I have create an action called search inside my index controller like below :

```
def search
  @item = Item.search params[:search]
end
```

but when I press the "search" button I won't get any proper answer from Rails server all I'll get is :

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/search"

and this is my route.rb

```
match "/search/:search" => "items#search"

post "items/:id/like" => "items#like"


resources :items do
  put :like,   :on => :member
end

  resources :items do
      resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments

#  root :to => 'items#index'
  root :to => 'items#list'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

and my url is like this after hitting "search" button :

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/search
```

-----------------update-------------------------

and if I say :

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/search/criteria
```

it will work

-----------------end update-------------------------

which I guess the problem is with passing parameter from form to the appropriate action . because if I call the above url manually and I just put a search criteria in it , it will work flawlessly but with form no chance!

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the :search part. Parameters that are GET or POST'd to your server aren't url chunks that need to be matched, they are always available in the params hash.

```
match '/search' => "index#search"
```

**EDIT**

It's not standard to want to construct URLs the way you are doing. criteria that the forms generate will be of the format "?thing=value" not /value. Try sending the criteria yourself in that format.

If you want to handle /search/:criteria then this would make the "search" variable available in your controller (NOT in the params[:search] hash)

```
match "/search/:search" => "items#search"
```

Comment: if I do the way you say I'll get another error : "TypeError in ItemsController#search"  and I'll get another error even if I pass parameters directly : "Routing Error"

Comment: that typererror isn't related to routing. Try printing out params.inspect or using the debugger to see what the error is in your search function

Comment: I'll get error even if I provide a criteria to the search action manually so which means the routing has problems or if you have any idea please write here cause I seriously don't have any other idea.

Comment: What do you mean "provide criteria manually"? In the URL? Can you update your question with the URLs you're trying as well as the search function of your Item model